# Complex root problem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $u$ be a complex root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$.
> If there exits $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $au^3+bu^2+cu+d=0$ then $a=b=c=d=0$.

My idea is to compute the roots $u$ of $x^{5}=1$ then compare the Re and Im of $au^3+bu^2+cu+d=0$, but it seems to be a laborious task. Does anyone have nicer approach to this problem?

Comment: What has this to do with [tag:linear-algebra]?

Comment: It kinda linear independent, I think

Comment: The question is wrong as stated *because of linear algebra*: four vectors $1, u, u^2, u^3$ cannot ever be $\Bbb R$-linear independent in $\Bbb C$ (that is only 2-dimensional over $\Bbb R$). Did you mean $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: What's your background here? The polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ can be shown to be irreducible by setting $x=y+1$ and using Eisenstein's criterion on the resulting polynomial in $y$.

Comment: You should try reading about [roots of unity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist yes, I edited. Thank for your comment

Comment: @red_trumpet I knew, but does it help anything?

Comment: Since it is irreducible and its degree is $4$, none of its roots can be a root of a non-null polynomial with degree smaller than $4$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos could u explain why  none of its roots can be a root of a non-null polynomial with degree smaller than 4?

Comment: $1,\zeta_p,\zeta_p^2,\ldots , \zeta_p^{p-2}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, for $p$ prime. Here $p=5$.

Comment: If $\eta$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ and if $\eta$ is also a root of some other non-null polynomial $q(x)$, then $p(x)\mid q(x)$, and therefore the degree of $q(x)$ is greater than or equal to the degree of $p(x)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $p(x)|q(x)\iff$ all the roots of $p(x)$ (include multiple roots) are also roots of $q(x)$. So, why you can conclude $p(x)|q(x)$ even if you don't check all the roots of $p(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. The polynomial $1+X+X^2+\cdots +X^{p-1}$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ by (shifted) Eisenstein, hence the field degree satisfies $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_p):\Bbb Q]=p-1$, and the elements
$$
1,\zeta_p,\zeta_p^2,\ldots , \zeta_p^{p-2}
$$
are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$. Note that for the sum of all powers we have
$1+\zeta_p+\zeta_p^2+\cdots +\zeta_p^{p-1}=0$. For $p=5$ we obtain your case, with $u=\zeta_5=e^{2\pi i/5}$.